# How do I connect to a database which I am viewing in Azure data studio, in R studio?

Tags: r, macos, azure-data-sync

I am trying to access a database which I am viewing in Microsoft Azure Data Studio, in R studio. I do not come from a programming background so I am a little confused. I am also completing this from a Mac Computer.
I am most confused about the driver section? How do I set up a driver to Azure Data studio?

I have read online about ODBC manager but again I am not sure how to use this?

I have hidden both the server and the database name, however they come from a cloud.

```
install.packages("DBI")
install.packages("odbc")
library(odbc)
install.packages("unixODBC")
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver   = "Azure",
                      Server   = "********",
                      Database = "*****",
                      UID      = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user"),
                      PWD      = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"),
                      Port     = 1433)
```

Please help,

Thank you.

Comment: Kindly go through the link below:
Azure Data Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/quickstart-sql-database?view=sql-server-2017

For databases using R studio: https://db.rstudio.com/databases/microsoft-sql-server/